# How to fill a query sql with multiple optional parameter in PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql

I explain myself...

I have a form with fill the query (eg.):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id=? AND name=? AND sex=? AND year=? AND class=?
```

but only the "id" is mandatory, all the other parameter are optional.
How can I fill (or re-create) the prerared statement for that query ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd either have to use multiple prepared statements or just create a statement on the fly, checking which parameters you have.

Like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?";
if( nameParameter != null ) {
  query += " AND name=?"; //don't never ever directly add the value here
}
...
```

**Update/Warning**: Don't directly add the parameter values to the query string but use `PreparedStatement` and the like instead. As displayed above the query string should only contain placeholders for the values (eg. `?`) in order to prevent SQL-injection attacks.

What I mean is, ***do NOT do the following***:

```
if( nameParameter != null ) {
  //NEVER EVER, REALLY I MEAN IT, DON'T DO THIS
  query += " AND name='" + nameParameter + "'"; 
}
```

Comment: tks... it's the way that I used, it seems the "cleanest" way

Comment: I know there are frameworks out there for dynamic query generation, but this seems to be the best solution for many cases. +1

Comment: but this approach is prone to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @aishu you'd still use a PreparedStatement and set the parameter value using that object. Of course you should _not_ directly append the value to the query string. I'll add a warning to my answer.