# URL parameters to SQL WHERE

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, get

My webapp mostly consists of longer tables displaying different kinds of data.
I'm using SQL Server, Node.js for the server and React for the client. I'm using the [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package for Node.js -> SQL Server connection.

Let's say I have a table **Licenses**, with fields:

**user_id**: Int

**type**: Varchar(2) e.g. 'AA', 'BB', 'CC'

**subscription**: Bit (0,1)

**created_on**: timestamp e.g. 1518962994

I currently have a route /licenses which pulls all licenses from my API `SELECT * FROM Licenses`. I would like to filter the results by providing **optional** parameters in the URL e.g.

`/licenses?type=AA&type=BB&subscription=1`

By using the [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) package, I'm able to read the parameters on the server:

```
{ 
    type: ['AA', 'BB'],
    subscription: 1
 }
```

The question is, how do I convert this to be used in a SQL query?

The tool is behind a password and API calls are authenticated.

This worked pretty well, but it's certainly wrong and very prone to SQL injections:

```
    let where = ' WHERE ';

    Object.keys(params).forEach((key, i) => {
        let part = '';

        if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
            let joined = params[key].join('\',\'')
            part += key + ' IN (\'' + joined + '\')';
        }
        else {
            part += key + '=' + '\'' + params[key] + '\'';
        }

        where += part;

        if (i + 1 !== Object.keys(params).length) {
            where += ' AND ';
        }
    });
```

Comment: Create PrepredStatements with `?` SQL parameters.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Wasn't sure how to do it with optional parameters though. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8277335/8105522) look good? It's for Java but can easily be changed to JS.

Comment: Well unfortunately dealing with optional parameters requires some sort of query-building framework. I work with a home-grown Java system that deals with that (for Postgresql but it'd be pretty much the same with SQL Server). It lets you start with a basic "family" of queries, and then allows for optional predicates, sorting, etc. It's worth it for pretty much putting an end to SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let where = [];
let values = [];

Object.keys(params).forEach((param) => {
    let value = params[param];
    let cond = (Array.isArray(value)) ? 
        ' in ' + value.map(e => '?').join(', ') :
        ' = ' + value;

    // You must check that param is correct field name e.g. read meta-data from db
    where.push(param + cond); 
    values.push.apply(values, value);
});

where = ' where 1 = 1 ' + where.join(' AND ');
...
db.exec(query + where, values, (err, rows) => ...)
```